# Convert a list of day/opening hours to a more readable format

Tags: c#, list, algorithm, linq

I have a silly little problem I'm having some difficulty getting a neat solution for. All I try turns messy and too complicated very quickly.

The problem is this.
Given a list of key value pair like:

- "Mon", "09:00-17:00"
- "Tue", "09:00-17:00"
- "Wed", "09:00-17:00"
- "Thu", "08:00-18:00"
- "Fri", "09:00-17:00"

We should return a simplified list that looks like this

- "Mon-Wed", "09:00-17:00"
- "Thu", "08:00-18:00"
- "Fri", "09:00-17:00"

Some ideas for some clever solutions would be appreciated!

Comment: It doesn't have to be clever; it just has to work.  I suggest using an ordinary loop for this, not Linq.  It will be easier to write and easier to understand.

Comment: One thing that will help: writing an enum for the days of the week that gives you numeric equivalents for each day in the proper order.

Comment: You also need separate code that parses the times into a more useable representation like `TimeSpan` objects.

Comment: @RobertHarvey True you might be able to do something with grouping if the days had a numerical value so you could keep the order straight but that also seems like a less than ideal solution. I also don't quite get why having the time in TimeSpan would help. I'm not interested in the value. A string comparison like "09:00-17:00"=="09:00-17:00" should work.

Anyhow as you said the less than neat solution I have will have to do for now.

Comment: You should key off of the time range, since that is the part that stays the same.  Converting the day of week to a number as suggested will be helpful in maintaining order and for your custom day range groupings ie. Mon-Wed, vs. Mon, Tues, Wed

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    var newList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    var startDay = origList[0].Key;
    var endDay = startDay;
    var currentTime = origList[0].Value;
    foreach (var element in origList)
    {
        if (element.Value != currentTime)
        {
            var key = startDay + (startDay == endDay ? "" : "-" + endDay);
            newList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, currentTime));
            startDay = element.Key;
            currentTime = element.Value;
        }
        endDay = element.Key;
    }
    var lastKey = startDay + (startDay == endDay ? "" : "-" + endDay);
    newList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(lastKey, currentTime));
```

result

```
    Mon-Wed 09:00-17:00
    Thu 08:00-18:00
    Fri 09:00-17:00
```